# F# Memoization Within a Class

Tags: functional-programming, f#, memoization

I am struggling to make Memoization work in F# when the function I want to Memoize is a **member of a class**.
The Dictionary appears to be cleared every time - and so nothing is actually memoized, the result is always recomputed. The same code but with the key functions outside of a calls of a class works just fine.

```fs
open System
module TestMemo

open System
open System.IO
open System.Collections.Generic

let Memoize f =
    let dict = Dictionary<_, _>()
    fun c ->
        let exists, value = dict.TryGetValue c
        match exists with
        | true -> value
        | _ -> 
            let value = f c
            dict.Add(c, value)
            value

type MyClass() as this = 
    let rec AddToOne(x) = if x <= 1 then 1 else x + AddToOne(x-1)
    let rec AddToOneSkip(x) = if x <= 1 then 1 else x + AddToOneSkip(x-2)
    
    member this.MemoAddToOne = Memoize AddToOne
    member this.MemoAddToOneSkip = Memoize AddToOneSkip

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    let x = new MyClass()
    
    for i in 1..100000 do
        Console.WriteLine(x.MemoAddToOneSkip(i))

    for i in 1..100000 do
        Console.WriteLine(x.MemoAddToOne(i))
    
    0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write this:

```
member this.MemoAddToOne = Memoize AddToOne
```

That's not a "value", but a *property*. A property in .NET is a pair of functions (get + set), but there are also read-only properties, which have only "get". And that's what you created here. They're basically functions in disguise.

So every time somebody accesses `x.MemoAddToOne`, they're basically calling a function, so every time the body is executed anew, thus making a new call to `Memoize` every time.

To avoid this, create the memoizers once and then return them from the property getter:

```
let memoAddToOne = Memoize AddToOne
member this.MemoAddToOne = memoAddToOne
```

Or use a shortcut for the same thing:

```
member val MemoAddToOne = Memoize AddToOne
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Perhaps I misunderstood your comment, but when I make that change I still don't believe the Memoization happens... i.e. I get a stackoverflow, and the dict never grows beyond 0.

Comment: Content of my class is now:
`type MyClass() = 
    let rec AddToOne(x) = if x <= 1 then 1 else x + AddToOne(x-1)
    member val MemoAddToOne = Memoize AddToOne`

Comment: @Eugene You get a stack overflow because your functions don't recurse into the memoized functions. In addition to that, they're not tail recursive.

Comment: Thank you both! Indeed I wasn't recursing on the memoized function.

Thanks a lot to all!